# How to render nested firebase data in listview with "react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

### How to render nested firebase data in listview with react-native

Hi everyone ! I am developing a beginner project using `Firebase` and `React-Native`. I have a problem and I want you to give me some advice or code on this problem.

**This is my firebase data**

```
{"Users" : {
"firebaseRandomKey" : {
  "IsValid" : true,
  "Name" : "Name",
  "Post" : {
    "PostText" : "lorem ipsum",
    "postUri" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4HGRIFivKQo/maxresdefault.jpg"
  },
  "Surname" : "Surname",
  "uri" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OEI2sJuOweU/hqdefault.jpg"
},}}
```

**This is my ListView renderRow**

```
renderRow(rowData) {
       return (
         <ScrollView ContainerStyle={styles.ScrollView}>
           <Text>{rowData.Name} {rowData.Surname}</Text>
           <Image source={{ uri: String(rowData.uri) }} style={styles.Photo} />
           <Text>{rowData.PostText}</Text>
           <Image source={{ uri: String(rowData.postUri) }} style=
           {styles.postPhoto} />
         </ScrollView>
       );
      }
```

So I can not reach my `PostText` and `postUri` because they are in the `"Post"`. How can i reach them in renderRow with `rowData`? thanks for your answers

[This is the page code](https://github.com/MuhammetYavuzCayli/firebaseexample/blob/master/discover.js)

[This is the page screenshots after update my code](https://github.com/MuhammetYavuzCayli/firebaseexample/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: can you try with `rowData.Post.PostText`

Comment: for better understanding about your json structure, you can try 
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and paste your json there

Comment: thanks your advices :) but i already tried rowData.Post.PostText and throw an error https://hizliresim.com/BAN4m9 :/

Answer (score 1):

have you change this one :

```
<Text>{rowData.PostText}</Text>
```

to this one :

```
<Text>{rowData.Post.PostText}</Text>
```

and this one too :

```
<Image source={{ uri: String(rowData.postUri) }} style=
           {styles.postPhoto} />
```

to this one :

```
<Image source={{ uri: String(rowData.Post.postUri) }} style=
           {styles.postPhoto} />
```

Comment: Thanks your answer :) but i already write that and throw an error like : 
https://hizliresim.com/BAN4m9